# Spyder Not Launching

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have two environments in which spyder just doesn't want to launch. I click the icon there is a waiting cursor then nothing happens. One of the two is totally new that I just made today. After installing some packaged (pip install pytrends was the last one) it stopped opening.

Note: the general spyder at: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder.exe does launch, but not the one for the environments.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This solves the problem:

```
conda upgrade qt
```

Comment: Works. I think the issue happens when other packages' installation downgrade Qt from their default dependency requirements. I did notice the downgrade operations did not work with Spyder open.

Comment: What is the best way to accomplish this if my environment is not connected to the internet?

Comment: it does not work for me. Even after I reset Spyder setting in anaconda, Spyder still cannot launch

Comment: @Kardi I am facing the same issue, Did you get any solution?

Comment: @spd, just reinstall the whole Anaconda and it works

Comment: in the newest version i had to use
"conda upgrade qtpy"

Answer (score 10):

Just try this :

1. uninstall pyQt using

`conda uninstall pyqt`

2. uninstall sip package

`conda uninstall sip`

3. then install these packages in following order

`conda install sip`

`conda install pyqt`

`conda upgrade spyder`

this worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

For me the outdated library was spyder.kernel. The best solution is to open a new python environment (just input 'py' in command line to build a new environment) and run the following script and it tells you what library is missing or outdated:

```
from spyder.app import start
start.main()
```

Comment: That at least got me some clues, although looks like the popup message still not reflected in the console output.

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to launch Spyder and Jupyter notebook from anaconda environment (Mac OS).

Following command worked for me:

```
conda uninstall tornado
conda install tornado==4.5.3
```

Just uninstall `tornado` and reinstall it.

Comment: You can install tornado with conda, like this `conda install tornado`, so you need to do that instead of using pip. That's because pip and conda are not interchangeable. I'd also suggest to update your answer and change pip for conda.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced a similar issue while running spyder from the anaconda navigator or the conda terminal.
To overcome this issue you just need to follow some simple steps.

1. open the anaconda navigator. ( You can also use anaconda prompt and type "anaconda-navigator" at the console)
2. Open the application and then follow the steps as shown in the image.
   here we are creating a new environment with a python of version 3.6. I think the 3.7 version is unstable and doesn't work properly. It worked for me, hope for you too !!!

see the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20QlK.png) and follow the steps.

it will take some time to download resources to set up the environment for the first time.

after following the steps launch the application. Make sure to run the environment first to be able to launch the application.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved in the newest version of conda. Currently it is on the conda canary channel, you can get it by running conda update conda -c conda-canary

[Reference](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8876)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
pip uninstall spyder
```

---

```
pip install spyder
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Spyder was launching in the environment which had issues. I just removed the environment and everything fell back in to place.

Use this to remove the environment:

```
conda env remove -n ENV_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Spyder IDE not launching
In my case I'm not installed the IDE in c-drive. After uninstalling and installing the Ide in the c-drive. It is launching.

If you are facing the same problem try to install in the windows c-drive.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share what it works for me because I don't have a clue why.

- I first started python in the terminal typing:
  python
- Then I pasted the following:
  from spyder.app import start
  start.main() \enter
- which showed this error:
  File "", line 1
  start.main()
  ^
  SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
- Then, I use line by line:
  from spyder.app import start \enter
- then:
  start.main() \enter

And spyder shows up. Don't know why it works this way but it worked for me. Hope it helps somebody.