# Anaconda Spyder doesn't launch

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to open Spyder and I have deleted multiple times the "spyder.lock" folder in user/directory but it doesn't work. This is the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\anaconda3\envs\EnvTest\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>


 sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 212, in main
    mainwindow.main(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3685, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3571, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 886, in setup
    from spyder.plugins.completion.plugin import CompletionManager
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\completion\plugin.py", line 22, in <module>
    from spyder.plugins.completion.languageserver.plugin import (
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\completion\languageserver\plugin.py", line 31, in <module>
    from spyder.plugins.completion.languageserver.confpage import (
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\completion\languageserver\confpage.py", line 31, in <module>
    from spyder.plugins.completion.languageserver.widgets.snippetsconfig import (
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\completion\languageserver\widgets\snippetsconfig.py", line 17, in <module>
    from jsonschema import validate as json_validate
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    __version__ = metadata.version("jsonschema")
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\anaconda3\envs\EnvTest\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 531, in version
    return distribution(distribution_name).version
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\anaconda3\envs\EnvTest\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 236, in version
    return self.metadata['Version']
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\anaconda3\envs\EnvTest\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 224, in metadata
    self.read_text('METADATA')
  File "C:\Users\pc-acer\anaconda3\envs\EnvTest\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 491, in read_text
    return self._path.joinpath(filename).read_text(encoding='utf-8')
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'read_text'
```

I don't know what i have to do. Please help!

Comment: This might not be a terribly elegant solution, but have you tried uninstalling spyder or anaconda and starting fresh?

Answer (score 1):

There might be 2 situation

1. You are using older version of python or something messed up so try reinstalling newer version of python
2. conda missing some dependencies.

   conda upgrade spyder

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125462/spyder-not-launching) thread.