# Cannot launch Spyder after upgrading Anaconda Navigator 3

Tags: python, spyder

I just upgraded Anaconda by using the command 'conda update --all' on MacOS but Spyder cannot be launched afterward. I have already tried reinstalled Anaconda and Spyder but still didn't work. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be launched"? How are you launching it? What happens? Are there any errors?

Comment: I clicked the 'launch' button of Spyder in Anaconda after upgrading but it doesn't work. When I want to close Anaconda, however, the pop-up window says Spyder is running.

Comment: Try doing some of the things mentioned in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125462/spyder-not-launching.